# iOS Swap Colors to Change Theme of App

Tags: ios, swift, themes, uicolor

I'm trying to implement a color-blind mode for my iOS app. Right now, I have 3 global variables for red, green, and blue defined as such:

```
var red : UIColor = UIColor(...)
var green : UIColor = UIColor(...)
var blue : UIColor = UIColor(...)
```

Now, I have a UIButton that the user can press to change to color-blind mode. Once this happens, I'm changing the global variables as such:

```
red = newRed
green = newGreen
blue = newBlue
```

However, this does not update the colors for any existing views that have already been loaded. Is there a way for me to update all controls that were red to the new red, green to the new green, and blue to the new blue without reloading the entire app? Thanks!

Update to post my button action:

```
func changeColor(sender: AnyObject) {
    red = UIColor(...) //this is different from the previous red
    green = UIColor(...) //this is different from the previous green
    blue = UIColor(...) //this is different from the previous blue
    //if I call viewDidLoad() again, then the colors are changed for all objects. However, I don't think this is the correct thing to do.
}
```

Comment: Post your button action.

Comment: @Michael I just posted it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never directly call `viewDidLoad()`. You need to ensure that your `IBOutlet`s are attached to your views inside of your view controller. Also, ensure that you are directly changing the `backgroundColor` property of the view. For example:

```
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```